# .htaccess file is firing off custom 404 page every time

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a simple `.htaccess` file in my root folder pointing to a custom 404 page that is designed to send an automatic email every time a 404 is encountered. I only have this one line in it, which could be attributing to the issue.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/cartonerp_live/404/404.php
```

However, any time a valid page is touched, it is firing off the email and I am not sure since it should only be when an invalid page 404 is hit.

Comment: is not an ideal solution to send an email every 404 once live the wordpress scanner bots/noise will trigger 1k's of emails per day, instead just log it, 404s are not errors. though is prob caused by the browser looking for a default favicon.

Comment: besides cant you look in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, for what the actual URL is? surly your not simply sending an email saying *site has a 404*

Comment: Its not a wordpress site, but a software run on PHP, and across multiple servers. I need it to send an email to our help desk with a few details, like the script and which organization, as well as a user friendly splash screen. That's why I have it sending emails instead of logfile.

Comment: I didn't say it was, what I said was bots scanning for wordpress.. unless your site implements /wp-admin.php and the 100s of other signature paths wp and other hack entrypoints/vectors/things have like /phpmyadmin, /pma, /db, /admin, /adminer.php /etc, its going to trigger a 404 for all of them. is better to log it and perhaps send the log every few days, vs on thread

Comment: Looks like i might be a bit over my head. I thought this would only get directed to my 404.php page when the server encountered an actual dead page, not on any traffic. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: _Redirecting_ to a 404 page is rather wrong to begin with. Clients will not get a 404 status code for the originally requested URL any more - that one just redirected them somewhere else. The will get a 404 _for_ `http://localhost/cartonerp_live/404/404.php`, telling them that _that_ resource did not actually exist.